# How to use new magic keyboard with MBP 2019 16inch?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, compatibility

On the [official website](https://www.apple.com/in/shop/product/MK2C3HN/A/magic-keyboard-with-touch-id-and-numeric-keypad-for-mac-models-with-apple-silicon-us-english?fnode=eb671fb48479b829b0bec6d3b4591ffcbe7516687ca697b4fee3328473d046a5814ee4fb968908480b1d01492225e909ad2278a5c0182487197b67d6493a57c01549baff7724aa3b68811ee6e16b369aa512acea355889aa66f706a70eb21889), it says that the new Magic Keyboard (with fingerprint sensor) is only compatible with Apple Silicon Macs, which would exclude the Intel MBP 2019 16inch model.

But is there a way to make it compatible?

Comment: What do you mean with compatible here: Make it work in general or make it work with Touch ID? Also, is this a theoretical question or are you facing a practical problem with that keyboard?

Comment: I'd be surprised if the keyboard didn't work entirely. I suspect it's only the Touch ID feature that doesn't work. I doubt there's a way to make it work.

Comment: I have not purchased it yet. I want to know if it is compatible or can be made compatible before making such an investment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried and can't seem to get my 2019 16" MBP to recognize the TouchID sensor on a new Magic Keyboard with TouchID.

This page seems to indicate only Apple Silicon models have the required ability to connect to the Secure Enclave. (For more information, see Apple's Support document: [Magic Keyboard with Touch ID](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/magic-keyboard-with-touch-id-secf60513daa/web))

So, absent some hack that I can't seem to find, it seems the answer is likely "no, it doesn't work".

Comment: For clarity, you can confirm that all the other keys, except for TouchID, work perfectly?

Comment: Only the TouchID key fingerprint sensor is inop. Everything else works fine.